# tomcat relative paths settings

Tags: java, tomcat, relative-path

I have deployed a app on tomcat. Some of the libraries used by the app use relative paths to resources. Therefore, they search the resources in TOMCAT-HOME/relative-path.
 I can not create links nor copy resources to TOMCAT-HOME folder. Also I can not change the code of the libraries and use application context.
 Can I somewhere in Tomcat configuration specify the "working directory" for this app alone.
I've tried using Context container, but I can not get my head around it.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I'm rather curious here.  Last time I came across the TOMCAT_HOME setting was when Tomcat was in version 3.x, the version written by James Duncan Davidson at Sun Microsystem in the previous millennium.  With the introduction of Tomcat 4 (in 2004) the tomcat's home folder is pointed at by the env. var. CATALINA_HOME.  What application still runs with Tomcat 3.x ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this inside your `server.xml`

```
<Context cachingAllowed="false" docBase="C:\ProgramFiles\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\apache-tomcat-5.5.29\temp" path="/tmpimages" privileged="true">
  </Context>
```

and use `/tmpimages` inside your source code.

Answer (score 0):

From the question you have asked , i can understand that you have problems accessing the TOMCAT-HOME folder . Why dont you try adding a ../ in front of all the paths that wants to access the TOMCAT-HOME folder ?

Comment: the thing is that I can not put folders with resources in a tomcat home folder, so I can not reference them. I need a way of saying to the app that all relative paths start from some folder. For example, I set a folder /home/user/data/ as a "current working" folder for the web app, so when i ask for a file with the relative path in the app it looks in the /home/user/data folder.