# Tomcat servlet relative path referring to root

Tags: java, file, tomcat, servlets, relative-path

I'm using Java Spring Boot and deploying to Tomcat 8.1 webapp.

When I create a new File() with a relative path, it is referring to the absolute root of the system.

For instance,

```
File x = new File("./temp.txt");

System.out.println("X Path: " + x.getAbsolutePath());
```

The output is

```
/./temp.txt
```

Why is this?  I'm getting a Java.nio.File.AccessDeniedException because Tomcat does not have permissions to write to the root.

The code is a third party library creating a cache file, so I can't feasibly just change to absolute path.

What causes Tomcat to use / as my working directory?

Comment: The third party library I'm using specifically used "./pemfile_cached".  The code above was me confirming that I get the same results.  Here's the third party library, line 197: https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver/blob/master/src/com/machinepublishers/jbrowserdriver/StreamConnectionClient.java

Comment: You may want to check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680637/servlet-tomcat-relative-file-path). TLDR: you can use `System.setProperty("user.dir", <path>)` to set the current directory, instead of Tomcat's

Comment: If that works, I'll save that as a last resort.  I'd rather not have to explicitly set my current working directory for every call here, but if I have to I will.  I suspect tomcat configuration (or missing configuration) is the issue but I'm not sure where to start looking for that.

Comment: The reasons of that are written in [the post I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680637/servlet-tomcat-relative-file-path). A solution kinda clean can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183967/tomcat-relative-paths-settings?rq=1)

Comment: I don't understand.  The post you linked makes no mention of the _absolute path_.  When I use System.getProperty("user.dir") it returns a simple "/".  Shouldn't it return (as your link suggests) $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/YOUR_WEB_APP/ instead?

Comment: Indeed. Are you running an **embedded** tomcat server or are you deploying the spring application on an **external** tomcat?

Comment: It's an external tomcat server

Answer (score 1):

So I determined the problem.  Tomcat, when executed as a service (CentOS: systemctl start tomcat) the WorkingDirectory defaults to root if it is not set.

By editing the tomcat.service file in /etc/systemd/system and adding under the [Service] section the following:

```
WorkingDirectory=/opt/tomcat
```

I was able to move the directory where the third party library was writing.